# Can't instantiate an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm trying to load up an array of objects that is an array itself, so to speak.  So I have an array of names(members) then I'm making a master list that will have name, bugs, enhance, etc. in one row for every name.  So I run a simple for loop to load master list but it is telling me that for (0) i, masterList[i].name cannot be loaded because it is undefined.  Is there a way around this?  Thanks

```
 var mem = getMembers();//get a array of members
 var memlen = mem.length;
 var masterList = [memlen]; //set to number of members
 for(i=0; i < memlen; i++){  
    masterList[i].name = mem[i];  //set .name to the members list name at i
    masterList[i].bugs = 0; 
    masterList[i].enhance = 0; 
    masterList[i].epic = 0; 
    masterList[i].dev = 0; 
    masterList[i].high = 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correct version would be:

```
var mem = getMembers();//get a array of members
var memlen = mem.length;
var masterList = []; //set to number of members
for(var i=0; i < memlen; i++){  
    masterList[i] = {
        name: mem[i],  //set .name to the members list name at i
        bugs: 0, 
        enhance: 0, 
        epic: 0, 
        dev: 0, 
        high: 0
    };
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To create your array with a predefined size, use this :

```
masterList = new Array(memlen);
```

(with `masterList = [memlen]` you were just creating an array whose first item is `memlen`. This wasn't so problematic because the array was automatically growing in the loop but that wasn't your intent)

After that, you need to create each `masterList[i]` :

```
var masterList = new Array(memlen);
for (var i=0; i < memlen; i++){  
    masterList[i] = {};
    masterList[i].name = mem[i];  //set .name to the members list name at i
```

If you don't do it, it's `undefined`, hence the error you have.

I also added `var` in the loop declaration to avoid the accidental erasing of another variable named `i`.

Comment: Except you don't need need to initialize the Array's length anyways. Just use `[]`

Answer (score 0):

`var x = [7];` does not create a 7-element array. it creates a single element array, index 0, with value 7. You need to do `var x = array(7)` instead, plus initialize each of those elements to be an object instead, within your loop.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't set a length. It just creates a new Array with a single member set to the length.

```
var masterList = [memlen]; //set to number of members
```

---

Since you seem to already have an Array, you can use `.map` to build a new one.

```
 var mem = getMembers();
 var masterList = mem.map(function(item) {
    return {
        name: item.name, bugs: 0, enhance: 0, epic: 0, dev: 0, high: 0
    };
 });
```

Comment: `map` doesn't work on IE8 : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: [Compatibility patch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility)

Comment: Any reason for the down-vote? If you don't understand the code, simply ask about it, and I'll explain how it works.